# When I rotate an UIImageView with the transform property, the edges pixellate

Tags: ios, uiimageview

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to do antialiasing on a rotated view?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1315772/how-to-do-antialiasing-on-a-rotated-view)

I'm trying to rotate some UIImageViews using this technique:

```
imageView.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(r);
```

where r is a float usually between -0.3 and 0.3.

The problem is that the images (which are derived from square jpegs) that are rotated have jagged edges (pixellation), because they are at an angle after the transform. Is there a way to fix this so the edges are smooth (i.e. antialiased)?

Comment: anti-aliasing - or use vector art if possible

Comment: I can't use vector art in this case. How do I apply anti-aliasing?

Comment: I would like to know that as well :) - could you edit your question so it mentions AA?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is a key that you can set in Info.plist that enables antialiasing of the edges: UIViewEdgeAntialiasing.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html

Comment: Great..In your info.plist set : "Renders with edge antialiasing" YES

Comment: yeah, it works well in layer,but i found the subview of view still has antialiasing