# Antialiasing edges of UIView after transformation using CALayer's transform

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiview, rotation, antialiasing

I have a `UIView` object that rotates using `CALayer`'s transform:

```
// Create uiview object.
UIImageView *block = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame....]

// Apply rotation.
CATransform3D basicTrans = CATransform3DIdentity;
basicTrans.m34 = 1.0/-distance;
blockImage.layer.transform = CATransform3DRotate(basicTrans, rangle, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

After rotating the edges of the object are not antialiasing. I need to antialias them.
Help me, please. How can it be done?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

One way to do this is by placing the image inside another view that's 5 pixels bigger. The bigger view should have a transparent rasterized border that will smooth the edges of the UIImageView:

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 3; 
view.layer.borderColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor; 
view.layer.shouldRasterize = YES; 
view.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
```

Then, place your UIImageView inside this parent view and center it (With 2.5 pixels around each edge).

Finally, rotate the parent view instead of the image view.

It works very well - you can also encapsulate the whole thing in class that creates the hierarchy.

Comment: You may want to add `view.layer.rasterizationScale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];` to avoid blurry on Retina screens.

Comment: This comment should be part of the answer. Setting 'shouldRasterize' property is not sufficient!

Comment: tounaobun's answer performs better. Check my comment below.

Answer (score 42):

Simply add this key-value pair to your *Info.plist*: `UIViewEdgeAntialiasing` set to `YES`.

Comment: Perfect and easiest solution.

Answer (score 32):

check `allowsEdgeAntialiasing` property of `CALayer`.

```
block.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = YES; // iOS7 and above.
```

Comment: just like above (Info.plist) but more granular control!  Excellent!

Comment: The accepted answer does work just like this one, but this one performs better. Both spend the same RAM, but this solution offers higher FPS to the user.

Comment: The documentation for this property says the value is NO if the Info.plist value is absent. Apparently, you can't simply set just this property but have to use it in conjunction with the plist. I've not tested what happens if the property is not set, but judging from the answer by  AddisDev, it defaults to yes in that case. So if there is a performance hit and you don't need antialiasing, it seems the thing to do is to set this value to NO.

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar issue when rotating around the z-axis. Setting shouldRasterize = YES prevented the jagged edges however it came at a performance cost. In my case I was re-using the views (and its layers) and keeping the shouldRasterize = YES was slowing things down.

The solution was,  to turn off rasterization right after I didn't need it anymore. However since animation runs on another thread, there was no way of knowing when the animation was complete...until I found out about an extremely useful CATransaction method. This is an actual code that I used and it should illustrate its use:

```
// Create a key frame animation
CAKeyframeAnimation *wiggle = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
NSInteger frequency = 5; // Higher value for faster vibration
NSInteger amplitude = 25; // Higher value for lower amplitude
// Create the values it will pass through    
NSMutableArray *valuesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
NSInteger direction = 1;

[valuesArray addObject:@0.0];

for (NSInteger i = frequency; i > 0; i--, direction *= -1) {
    [valuesArray addObject:@((direction * M_PI_4 * (CGFloat)i / (CGFloat)amplitude))];
}

[valuesArray addObject:@0.0];
[wiggle setValues:valuesArray];

// Set the duration
[wiggle setAdditive:YES];
[wiggle setValueFunction:[CAValueFunction functionWithName:kCAValueFunctionRotateZ]];
[wiggle setDuration:0.6];

// Turn on rasterization to prevent jagged edges (anti-aliasing issues)
viewToRotate.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;

// ************ Important step **************
// Very usefull method. Block returns after ALL animations have completed.
[CATransaction setCompletionBlock:^{
    viewToRotate.layer.shouldRasterize = NO;
}];
// Animate the layer
[viewToRotate.layer addAnimation:wiggle forKey:@"wiggleAnimation"];
```

worked like a charm for me.

I have not tried using this with implicit animations (i.e. animations that happen due to value change in animatable property for a non-view associated layer), however I would expect it to work as long as the CATransaction method is called before the property change, just as a guarantee the block is given to CATransaction before an animation starts.