# UIView's transform looks terrible

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, cgaffinetransform

I have a simple view with simple background. I need to rotate the view with it's content. 
The code is here:

```
    CGAffineTransform r = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(5 * M_PI / 180.0f);
    backView.transform = r;
```

I can't find and way make it look nice.

Here is the screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Where is the screenshot?

Comment: here) sorry, first time upload image here)

Comment: possible duplicate of [antialiasing edges of UIView after transformation using CALayer's transform](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8313804/antialiasing-edges-of-uiview-after-transformation-using-calayers-transform)

Comment: How did you get the blue background: by drawing it in `drawRect` or using a `UIImageView`?

Comment: view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blueColor]; The same will be if i use imageView

Comment: Really the problem is the same as antialiasing edges of UIView after transformation using CALayer's transform, Thanks will try to solve

Comment: It works good when i make layer.borderColor = [UIColor ____color____].CGColor; , where ____color_____ is the same as the background, really works, but if image is background i have problems, because clearcolor doesn't work, i look how to fix it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the key [`UIViewEdgeAntialiasing`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/general/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW5) in info.plist:

[image]

But as the documentation says, this can have a noticeable impact on performance.

Answer (score 1):

I think I remember reading somewhere about using a 1px clear border which causes the aliasing to appear on the border (which is transparent), and the inner square will be unaffected.

EDIT:

Not sure, but [this](http://d3signerd.com/image-anti-aliasing-in-objective-c/) may have been where I read my previous suggestion. There are also several other solutions, and one of them make work well but still provide acceptable performance, should sch's answer prove too taxing.