# CALayer border get fuzzy on rotation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I am using
  UIColor* clear = [UIColor blackColor];
 [self.layer setBorderColor:[color CGColor]];

to set the border for an image.It is adding border but when i tried rotating that image to 45 degree,90 degree so on ,that border starts getting fuzzy and its not fixed or straight anymore. How can image that border fix like a line always whatever i do..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9698441/uiviews-transform-looks-terrible

Answer (score 0):

```
UIColor* clear = [UIColor blackColor]; [self.layer setBorderColor:[color CGColor]];
```

looks like something weird ;\ what is self here?
try to

```
UIImageView *imgView = [[UIImageView alloc] setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"pic.png"]];
[self.view addSubview:imgView];
imgView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0f;
imgView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor blackColor] CGColor];
```

And don't forget to include QuartzCore framework and `#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>`

Comment: I am creating custom class for UIImageView thats why self.

Comment: I think that you should try to set border properties out of self, somewhere in superview where you adding your image as subview as I wrote, just for experiment

Comment: but if u about pixelization - check out link by @George