# IOS - When I rotate a UIView the edges become distorted

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

[image: Distorted UIView Screenshot]

I tried rotating a UIView using:

```
view.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: 45)
```

only to see the edges of the view looked very distorted.
Is this normal? And if it is, are there any workarounds to straighten the edges?

**EDIT**

I found that adding the piece of code below works the best

```
view.layer.allowsEdgeAntialiasing = true
```

Comment: Can you add a screenshot?

Comment: Still looked pretty distorted. I also ran this on my own ios device and got the same result.

Comment: try this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/12066215/6742121 and check my answer for swift 3.0 . @BrandonCornelio

Comment: Thank you! This helps a lot

Comment: you are welcome. @BrandonCornelio

Answer (score 5, accepted):

refer this link,

https://stackoverflow.com/a/8313978/6742121,

After that implement this for swift 3.0,

```
view.layer.borderWidth = 3
view.layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
view.layer.shouldRasterize = true
view.layer.rasterizationScale = UIScreen.main.scale()
```